# Inserting a row to users who have a value

Tags: mysql

I want to insert an achievement to users who have IsBeta = 1

It's easy to you understand, guys.

I have it to select users:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE IsBeta = 1;
```

I want to insert achievement to all users who has IsBeta = 1

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `users_achievements` (`UserID`, `AchievementID`) VALUES ('userId', '1')
```

Can someone help me with this? I hope you understand guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the select query in your insert:

```
insert into users_achievements (UserID, AchievementID)
select id, 1
from users
where IsBeta = 1;
```

Comment: But whete to put achievement ID?

Comment: @DiegoSouza - `select id, 1` ---- `id` will go into `UserID` column and `1` (i.e. the achievement Id) will go into the `AchievementID` column.

Comment: And I can `SELECT * FROM users_items WHERE ItemID = 1452` get userid of this query and add an achievement to users who has this item id?

Comment: @DiegoSouza - How will you assign the achievement id for these users? Is it fixed?

Comment: This works, thanks, man.`insert into users_achievements (UserID, AchievementID)
select UserID, 50
FROM users_items WHERE ItemID = 1452` Thank you for the anwser, saved me!

Comment: I can delete users_items of users who don't exists anymore??

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `users_achievements`
SELECT id, 1
FROM   Users
WHERE  IsBeta = 1
```